# Grep alias piped to nano. Nothing happens when command is issued

Tags: grep, pipe, alias, output, nano

I have a professor who stores homework assignments in many files spread across different sub-directories in a lecture folder with the header "TODO:" I'd like to output all these todo's to a single text file in nano instead of navigating from one assignment file to another.

I tried to make an alias for this command, since I use it so much, but whenever I try to execute it, the cursor just blinks and nothing happens.

```
alias todo='cd /home/csc103/Desktop/shared/csc103-lectures && grep -Rw "TODO:" --after-context=6  --include="*.cpp" . > todo.txt && nano todo.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

## Edit

by "Nothing Happens" I mean that the cursor keeps blinking and the next prompt doesn't come up. As in the left terminal pane in the image below.
[image: No Additional Prompt]

However, when I force-quit the process with ctrl-C I do end up in the directory I wanted the todo command alias to take me to. And there is a todo.txt file in there.
[image: Csc103-lectures is the right directory]

Also, if it's of any relevance I'm issuing these commands on an Arch Linux install in VirtualBox.

Comment: My guess is your `grep` didn't find anything, so it returned a nonzero exit status which means the last `&&` skipped your `nano` invocation.

Comment: @user14903: What do you mean by “nothing happens”?  Do you mean that ***nothing happens***?  Or that nano starts but the screen is blank?  Or that you get your shell prompt back?  What directory are you in after whatever happens, happens?  Is a `todo.txt` fle created?  What’s in it? Are you saying that this *exact same command* works when you type it, but not when you run it via an alias?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks for the pointers guys. The problem here was that grep was recursively searching for "TODO:" in the todo.txt file and then writing those results back to the todo.txt file. When I opened todo.txt it was filled with the same text looped over and over again. Evidently, I should have used the `--exclude="todo.txt"` option in `grep`. After adding that, it works perfectly.